Bus contention - possible momentary short circuit with 74HC
I have a tristate bus where both input and output are controlled via 74HC573 latches, with only one latch OE (output enabled) active at any time. My concern is that the signal update from the control store may not reach both (old and new latches') OE pins simultaneously, so there is the possibility for a momentary short circuit: When both latches are momentarily OE active, old latch output in a pin is low and respective output pin of the other latch is high.
I could avoid this by inserting a clock delay between disabling OE for the old latch and enabling it for the new one, but I would like to avoid the tick delay if possible. Also would not like to have the bus in high-Z since I have connected an 74HC181 there.
My question is: Is a possibility for this momentary short circuit valid? If so, could I ignore it or is it bound to destroy my chips in the long run? How could I mitigate it?

Welcome! Please add a (simplified) schematic.

From where does the OE control come from? Even if the signal does not hit the chips simultaneously, are they even sent simultaneously?

Welcome to SE/EE! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. You might want to read "[ask]" and other pages of the [help]. -- Each existing device has data sheets with timing information, propagation delay, maximum currents, and so on. You can use that information to calculate the minimum and maximum intervals with contention or open lines. In fact you can not avoid both the same time. Open lines are not such a big problem due to the lines' capacitance. However, be aware of glitches that occur in any case.


My question is: Is a possibility for this momentary short circuit valid? If so, could I ignore it or is it bound to destroy my chips in the long run?

Yes, your concern is indeed valid, it may destroy chips, so do not ignore it.

How could I mitigate it?

Solution 1:
A simple solution is to insert a resistor between each output pin and the bus.  Select the resistor to ensure that the current is limited to a safe value if a momentary short does occur.
The safe value will be provided by examining the datasheet.  First look under the section "Recommended Operating Conductions"; in this case the TI datasheet does not mention maximum output currents in this section.
So, we then look under the section "Absolute Maximum Ratings", and apply some engineering rules-of-thumb.

Link to above image:
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc573.pdf
I would select the lowest of all the output pin current limits in the table, and then divide it by 2.  We see Iok (output clamp current) has the lowest value there, of +/-25mA.
Divide this by 2 gives us 12.5mA.
Next you select the resistor to insert between each output pin and the bus, noting that if there is a momentary "short-circuit", one output will be HI the other will be LOW, and there will be two resistors between them.  Assuming the highest Vcc you will have is 5V, then we get:
R = 0.5 * 5V / 12.5mA = 0.5 * 400Ω = 200Ω  ==> 220Ω.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
HOWEVER...
this solution may not suit your application, for two reasons.
Reason 1:
When a bus contention occurs (two outputs are both trying to drive the bus to different logic values at the same time), then the bus voltage will be mid-way between logic 1 and logic 0, ie: indeterminant.  Now, whether this is a problem in your application will depend on sevefal factors, for example:

The duration of the "bus contention" (nano-seconds, micro-seconds,
milli-seconds).

The characteristics of the other devices connected to the bus.


For example: the same chip 74HC573 has limits on how long the inputs can be indeterminate.  This can be estimated from the limits on input transition times, which we can see ranges from between 400ns to 1000ns.  So if the indeterminate state lasts for more than, say, 200ns, I would start to become very concerned.  Read note 1 for more details:

(1) All unused inputs of the device must be held at VCC or GND to
ensure proper device operation. Refer to the TI application report,
Implications of Slow or Floating CMOS Inputs, literature number
SCBA004.

You will need to look up the matching details for the chip you mentioned (74HC181).

Reason 2:
This may slow down the bus excessively (you have not told us anything about the bus speeds).  A resistor will introduce a time delay, the bus node will be slower than the output pin of the latch.

Solution 2:
A variation on Solution 1 is to insert just one resistor between the output pin & the bus for just one of the chips.  This makes the other chip the dominant device, meaning, its output will determine the bus voltage, regardless of the output of the other chip.  Select the resistor to ensure that the current is limited to a safe value if a momentary short does occur.
This avoids problem #1 of the previous solution, since the bus is never in the indeterminant state.
However, in regards to problem #2 (time delays): the dominant chip will not cause time delays, but the sub-ordinate chip may have time delays.

Solution 3:
Add a simple disable pulse that occurs at each clock edge which disables the outputs of both latches momentarily & simultaneously.  Create a monostable that provides a momentary pulse that disables the output at a particular clock edge.  Select the clock edge polarity a disable pulse duration that suits your application.
For example, if your clock is 1MHz (500ns HI and 500ns LOW), and you are latching inputs on the rising edge, then you want the OUTPUT ENABLE to de-asserted momentarity on the same edge that the inputs are latched.  Choose a duration for the disable of about one-quarter the clock HI time, so ~125ns.
